# ASP.Net Double Web Form Submit Conflict

Tags: asp.net, forms, double, submit

Hello community of StackOverflow :) I just started learning and creating my first web application with ASP.Net I'm no professional programmer or web designer but I'm finding some videos when I'm getting stuck. Today I'm posting here because I haven't find anything to solve my problem. I have a login widget on my Masterpage and it works but when I am in the Registration page the 2 forms (login widget and registration forms) conflict. It actually happens because of the Required field validators, when I try to login and I am in my Registration page all the required field validators  are triggered in the Registration form. Same thing happens with the RFVs in the login widget when I try to make a registration. So is there anybody know a code (C#) on how can I seperate these 2 forms? Thank you all for reading this have a nice day :)

Comment: can you show the code ?

Answer (score 0):

This is my Registration code:`MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd;
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand com;
    String queryStr;
    String checkuser;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccountDB"].ToString();
    conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connString);
    conn.Open();
    string checkuser = "SELECT count(*) FROM account.account WHERE login='" + Username.Text + "'";
    com = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    if (temp == 1)
    {
        Labeluser.Text = "Αυτό το Όνομα χρήστη υπάρχει ήδη!";
        conn.Close();
    }
    else
        CreateAccount();
}
private void CreateAccount()
{
    try
    {
        String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccountDB"].ToString();
        conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connString);
        conn.Open();
        queryStr = "";
        queryStr = "INSERT INTO account.account (login,password,real_name,social_id,email,question1,answer1,status,gold_expire,silver_expire,safebox_expire,autoloot_expire,fish_mind_expire,marriage_fast_expire,money_drop_rate_expire,coins) VALUES ('" + Username.Text + "' ,'" + pass1.Text + "' ,'" + realname.Text + "' ,'" + delete.Text + "' ,'" + mail1.Text + "' ,'" + secq.Text + "' ,'" + seca.Text + "' ,'BLOCK' ,'2099-12-31 23:59:59' ,'2099-12-31 23:59:59' ,'2099-12-31 23:59:59' ,'2099-12-31 23:59:59' ,'2099-12-31 23:59:59' ,'2099-12-31 23:59:59' ,'2099-12-31 23:59:59' ,'0')";
        cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteReader();
        regPar.Text = "Η εγγραφή σου ολοκληρώθηκε με επιτυχία! Ένα E-Mail ενεργοποίησης έχει σταλεί στον φάκελο «Εισερχόμενα» (ή «Ανεπυθήμητα») της διεύθυνσης E-Mail που δήλωσες.";
        regForm.Visible = false;
        regBot.Visible = false;
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Labeluser.Text = "Σφάλμα εγγραφής! Ίσως αυτά βοηθήσουν:" + ex.ToString();
    }
}`
```

This is my Masterpage (loginwidget) code:

```
 MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd;
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader reader;
String queryStr;
String name;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void LoginW_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccountDB"].ToString();
    conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connString);
    conn.Open();
    queryStr = "";
    queryStr = "SELECT * FROM account.account WHERE login='" + User.Text + "' AND password='" + Pass.Text + "'";
    cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    name = "";
    while (reader.HasRows && reader.Read())
    {
        name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("real_name"));
    }
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        Session["uname"] = name;
        Response.BufferOutput = true;
        Response.Redirect("Account/Panel.aspx", false);
    }
    else
    {
        loginWidLab.Text = "Μη έγκυρο Όνομα χρήστη ή Κωδικός πρόσβασης!";
    }
    reader.Close();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Sorry for any mistakes to this post I don't know how to use Stack Overflow yet :P

Answer (score 0):

## FIXED!!! - For those who are having the same problem go to your Validation Controls and add `ValidateGroup="XXXX or whatever you want"`. Apply this change to all your validation controls AND your submit button :)